# Deploy Azure function from C# code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to deploy Azure Function runtime (i-e like we can create service bus topic subscription using c# code). We have requirement that Azure Function triggers automatically on multiple service bus topics(s) subsciprtion(s). But azure function can only trigger on one service bus topic subscription.So, is there a way to add new function runtime usng C# code (we want to change "topicName" and (or)  "subscriptionName" in function.json file)

Comment: You could generate a `function.json` per queue and then upload them via Kudu API or push to CI/CD

Comment: @Mikhail We need create to new function (run.csx and function.json file) per queue?

Comment: Either that, or use a single precompiled dll and `function.json` per subscription